# NotificationCompat.Builder setAutoCancel not working in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, flags, android-pendingintent

I use NotificationCompat.Builder in an Activity and setAutoCancel(true) works fine, but the same is not working inside a BroadcastReceiver -the notification just keep showing up in the device regardless how many times the user clicks it. How to disable the notification upon user clicks in this case?

I also using this code together with the above and not working.
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, dailyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Builder.setContentIntent(pi);

Comment: what are you trying to do inside BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: yes, but seems it's not working properly inside the BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are doing is setting up an acitivity pending intent. It will launch activity upon clicking the notification. Change your PendinIntent to send broadcast like this:-

```
pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, dailyIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 

         // notice getBroadcast()
```

where  `dailyIntent` is an intent for broadcast. This will send the mentioned broadcast intent upon clicking the notification.

Comment: I think OP is trying to launch an activity. He's trying to show a notificaiton that will launch a new activity when triggered. I have the same problem 'sometimes'. set auto cancel wont work and the notification wont go away when tapped